# ¿Cómo obtener solamente resultados de una tabla sin que estos tengan valores asignados según otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

soy bastante nuevo aprendiendo sql y me surgió una duda de como realizar una consulta sql especifica. tengo dos tablas sql en la que ambas comparten un valor llamado "id_sede" en la primera tabla tengo valores de varias id de sedes y en la segunda valores de esas id pero asignadas junto con un valor "id_concurso" y lo que quiero hacer es que al realizar las consultas me devuelva solamente las sedes que no tengan un concurso asignado

esta es la primera tabla llamada "sede"

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| id_sede |         email         |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       1 | ejemplo@gmail         |
|       2 | prueba@hotmail        |
|       3 | pepe@gmail            |
|       4 | correoejemplo@hotmail |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

y esta es la segunda llamada "sede_concurso"

```
+---------+-------------+
| id_sede | id_concurso |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           1 |
|       1 |           3 |
|       2 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+
```

intento poner el siguiente codigo sql

```
SELECT sede.id_sede FROM sede, sede_concurso WHERE sede.id_sede <> sede_concurso.id_sede AND id_concurso=1;
```

y obtengo como resultados

```
+---------+
| id_sede |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       3 |
|       3 |
|       4 |
|       4 |
+---------+
```

cuando solo quiero que me regrese en ese caso solamente 3 y 4 (sin que se repitan) que son las sedes que no estan asignadas al concurso 1

el resultado que espero

```
+---------+
| id_sede |
+---------+
|       3 |
|       4 |
+---------+
```

Comment: Consulta sedes con una Combinación/Unión/Conjunción Externa Izquierda a sedes concurso donde el identificador de sede sea nulo.

Comment: Hola Roberto, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
select s1.id_sede 
from sede s1
where s1.id_sede not in (
                         select c.id_sede
                         from sede_concurso c
                        )
```

Se hace una **subconsulta** que devuelva todos los **id_sede** de la **tabla sede_concurso**, y sobre los registros devueltos por esta **subconsulta** se hace una consulta que utilizando el **operador not in** devuelva todos los **id_sede** de la **tabla sede** que no se encuentran en los registros devueltos por la **subconsulta** antes descrita.