# ¿Cómo puedo consultar registros no procesados?

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access

Buen día, estoy trabajando en Access y tengo las siguientes entidades relacionadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla RECIBIDO tiene los siguientes datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la tabla PROCESO los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los registros se almacenan en RECIBIDO y alguno de ellos pasan a PROCESO. Deseo hacer una consulta que me liste los registros que están en RECIBIDO pero no en PROCESO. Es decir, quiero hacer una tabla donde sólo se muestren los registros con números de orden 2, 4 y 5 (ya que solo están en RECIBIDO pero no en PROCESO) ¿Es posible hacer eso o es necesario cambiar la configuración de la base?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes? El tipo de consulta que necesitas es [algo como esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686266/5587982). Solamente tienes que cambiar los nombres de tablas/columnas relacionadas.

Comment: Consulta recibidos con una *Combinación/Unión/Conjunción Externa Izquierda* a procesados donde el número de orden sea nula.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489677/como-obtener-solamente-resultados-de-una-tabla-sql-sin-que-estos-tengan-valores/489708#489708 revisa esta publicacion, resuelve el mismo problema que tienens, lo unico q tienes q hacer es adaptar tu codigo

Comment: Lo que necesitas es, exactamente, esto: [Comparar dos tablas y buscar registros no coincidentes](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/comparar-dos-tablas-y-buscar-registros-no-coincidentes-cb20ad48-4eba-402a-b20d-eaf10a5d1cb4) Access incorpora un asistente que te va a facilitar la creación de esta consulta :)  Con el enlace verás las instrucciones.